# Getting selected rows from listview not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am binding some data from remoter server database to my listview. I have made one column to select the row with checkbox & on button click I want to update status of those selected rows. Problem is the code which I am using is not able to find checkbox control inside listview & which resulting unable to select rows.

I have set checkbox tooltip to row ID to get selected ID of row. Listview gets bind perfectly with checkbox control inside. When put a breakpoint I noticed that 'IF' condition (if (item is CheckBox)) is not getting true hence it unable to run further code.

```
List<string> ListItems = new List<string>();
foreach (void el_loopVariable in shipments.Items) {
    el = el_loopVariable;
    foreach (void item_loopVariable in el.Controls) {
        item = item_loopVariable;
        if (item is CheckBox) {
            if (((CheckBox)item).Checked == true) {
                ListItems.Add(((CheckBox)item).ToolTip);
                Session["selectedConsignments"] = ListItems.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Listview (For simplicity I am just putting one column of that checkbox)

```
<asp:ListView ID="shipments" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell13" runat="server">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Does your code even compile? What does `void` do in foreach loop.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya sorry but actually I am vb.net developer. I just converted my vb code to c# from telrik. Because I noticed VB posts gets unanswered mostly that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what exact problem you might have with the VB code of yours.
But you are doing overwork to identify the checkbox in listview items.
You can use `FindControl` which takes controlId as parameter and find any control matching with that Id in the parent control.

Consider writing your code as following.

```
List<string> ListItems = new List<string>();
foreach (var el_loopVariable in shipments.Items)
{
    //Passing id "chk" to FindControl method of current ListViewItem and trying to cast it as Checkbox
    var checkBox = el_loopVariable.FindControl("chk") as CheckBox;
    if (checkBox != null && checkBox.Checked)
    {
        ListItems.Add(checkBox.ToolTip);
    }
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

You also do not need to declared "runat=server" for `td` if you are not going to access it at your server side code.

Here is VB.NET version of the same code.

```
Dim ListItems As New List(Of String)()
For Each el_loopVariable As ListViewItem In shipments.Items
    Dim checkBox As CheckBox = TryCast(el_loopVariable.FindControl("chk"), CheckBox)

    If checkBox IsNot Nothing AndAlso checkBox.Checked Then
        ListItems.Add(checkBox.ToolTip)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. your solution worked for me. And yes "runat=server" I have given because I need to use cell to change it's css from code behnd. Anyways Tysm.

Answer (score 0):

```
// here:
<td id="cell13" runat="server">
```

There is an upper parent control, So try:

```
item.Controls[0] is CheckBox
```

But as I have read with compiled MSIL code if you have used:

```
CheckBox chk = item.Controls[0] as CheckBox;
if(chk != null)
// is executed faster
```